# How to take stack trace of node.js process running on AWS fargate?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, containers

My node.js application is running on AWS fargate as a docker image. I am struggling to figure out how to capture stack trace in the event of troubleshooting slow response times. Can anyone provide help?

Comment: The logs from tasks/containers run in by ECS/fargate should be available in Cloudwatch.

Comment: Thx. I know where to find logs. What I am not sure of is how to capture the stack trace/thread dump? Typically in Java application you do `kill -3 <pid>` that will produce the stack traces/thread dump, but not able to find something similar in node.js